# unknown id of the message

Tags: python, gmail-api

The script:

```
>     results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()
>     messages = results.get('messages', [])
> 
>     if not messages:
>         print("No messages found.")
>     else:
>         print("Message snippets:")
>         for message in messages[::-1]:
>             msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
>             print(msg['snippet'])
>             messageid = msg['id']
>             service.users().messages().delete(userId='me', id=messageid).execute()
>             break
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
```

Hey,
I wanted this program to take my oldest email, print it out, and then delete this message.
However the I am not sure what the id is and I'm always getting errors like this:

```
    Message snippets:
Google Banner Hallo Gmail, willkommen bei Google. Mit Ihrem neuen Konto können Sie Google-Produkte, ‑Apps und ‑Dienste nutzen. Für den Anfang haben wir hier einige nützliche Tipps für Sie
. Konto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmail.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "gmail.py", line 48, in main
    service.users().messages().delete(userId='me', id=messageid).execute()
  File "C:\Users\25jul\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in
 positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\25jul\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in exe
cute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/171f0100542b03d1? returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

thanks for the answers,
Julius

Comment: message `"Insufficient Permission"` can means you have no priivilages to delete messages and it may not be problem with ID.

Comment: to get message you use `message['id']` but for `delete` you use`msg['id']` - why don't you use the same `message['id']` to delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error you are getting `Insufficient Permission`, you are most probably not providing the necessary scope.

In order to call [Users.messages: delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete) you have to use this scope: **`https://mail.google.com/`**

The other calls you are making (`list` and `get`) are less restrictive and other scopes are accepted. That's why you are getting the error specifically when trying to delete the message.

#### Note:

- Even though this is not a problem of the `message ID` (you are retrieving it successfully) there is no need for `messageid = msg['id']` (you used `message['id']` before, you can use that again).

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages: delete > Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete#auth)